# How to suppress "Auto property synthesis will not synthesize property 'xxxx' declared in protocol 'yyy "?

Tags: objective-c

For debugging purposes, I am creating a class B which conforms to a certain `protocol A`.

```
@interface B: NSObject<A>
@end
```

Objective of this type hold internally another object `_internalObj` which also confirms to `protocol A`.
I also override some of the methods and re-route the others using:

```
- (void)forwardInvocation:(NSInvocation *)anInvocation
{
    if ([_internalObj respondsToSelector:
         [anInvocation selector]])
        [anInvocation invokeWithTarget:_internalObj];
    else
        [super forwardInvocation:anInvocation];
}
```

How, I am getting the following errors/warnings (depends on my project settings) which I am not successful suppressing.

```
"Auto property synthesis will not synthesize property 'xxxx' declared in protocol 'yyy "
```

I already tried the following but it didn't help:

```
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wobjc-property-synthesis"
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wobjc-missing-property-synthesis"
```

Any ideas?

Comment: In `@interface B: NSObject(A)` is A the name of the category. Adopt a protocol with `@interface B: NSObject <A>`.

Comment: Thanks @Willeke, I had a typo, fixed now.

Answer (score 2):

Just found `-Wobjc-protocol-property-synthesis` on http://fuckingclangwarnings.com and it's working.